# Pdfbox Text Extraction Exception

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdftotext

I am using PDF Box for the first time and I am using it to extract text from a certain region of the PDF.
I tested my program on 50 documents and it failed on 4 documents and gave me this exception.
Can someone shed more light on this? Or knows what is causing it to happen?

**Code**

```
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0 , 58 , 612 , 657);
stripper.addRegion( "region", rect );
List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

for( i=0 ; i<document.getNumberOfPages() ; i++)
{
    stripper.extractRegions( (PDPage)allPages.get( i ) );
    FileText += stripper.getTextForRegion( "region" );
}

System.out.println( FileText );
```

**Error Message**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writePage(PDFTextStripper.java:554)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripperByArea.writePage(PDFTextStripperByArea.java:190)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:446)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripperByArea.extractRegions(PDFTextStripperByArea.java:153)
    at pdf.box.App.main(App.java:68)
```

One of the files that gives this exception: https://files.fm/u/6srrrzxq

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? This bug was fixed at the end of 2015 ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1512 ) It is related to the usage of jdk7 (or higher).

Comment: @Tilman "It is related to the usage of jdk7" - well, strictly speaking it is due to a comparator which does not adhere to the comparator contract. Even though java 6 did not complain, it was a bug even then.